# Angular2 passing a JSON object to the constructor of a component

Tags: javascript, json, angular, electron

I have the following scenario where my first component `config.editor.component` does a lot of processing and creates a variety of different JSON objects.

I am happy with this approach. The template for this component then renders another component - `api.entry.component` using a *ngFor loop. How can I pass a JSON object which I created in my config.editor.component.ts into the constructor of my `api.entry.component`?

My current template looks like this :

```
<!-- loop and display all api components here -->
<ct-api-entry *ngFor="let api in apis"></ct-api-entry>
```

The object I want to pass into the constructor is actually 'api' seen above. This object is created in the config.editor.component.ts file as per this code which executes all as I would expect and assigns a JSON array to the `apis` variable :

```
 clicked(event){
      ipc.send('open-file-dialog');
      ipc.on('selected-directory', (event, obj) => {
        this.server_description = obj.description;
        this.features = obj.features;
        this.apis = obj.apis;
        this.wola_configs = obj.configs;
        this.connection_factories = obj.connection_factories;
      });
  }
```

All I really want is to be able to access the specific `api` from my template loop in the constructor of my api.entry.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-api-entry',
  templateUrl: 'api.entry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['api.entry.component.css']
})
export class APIEntryComponent {
//I NEED TO PASS THIS CONSTRUCTOR AN SPECIFIC JSON OBJECT FROM APIS IN THE CONFIG-EDITOR MAIN COMPONENT
  constructor() {
 //I WANT TO ACCESS MY JSON API OBJ IN HERE!
  }

}
```

I feel this must be quite simple but I am struggling to see how it works! Please help me understand how I can pass my JSON object in the *ngFor loop into the constructor of the component the template is building.

Comment: Just taking a stab as Im fairly new to angular2, i think you'd achieve what you want through a service? a shared service to be specific, where one component save the data through & to the service, and have another component to retrieve the stored data from the shared service

Comment: Unrelated, but I think you mean JavaScript object. JSON is object serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `api` using the `Input` decorator in your `ct-api-entry` component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-api-entry',
  templateUrl: 'api.entry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['api.entry.component.css']
})
export class APIEntryComponent {
   @Input() api: any;   
   constructor() {}
}
```

And then you pass it in the template:

```
<ct-api-entry *ngFor="let api of apis" [api]="api"></ct-api-entry>
```